# x86_64 Assembly Command Line Arguments

Tags: assembly, stack, command-line-arguments, x86-64

To get the command line arguments in x86_64 on Mac OS X, I can do the following:

```
_main:
  sub   rsp, 8         ; 16 bit stack alignment
  mov   rax, 0
  mov   rdi, format
  mov   rsi, [rsp + 32]
  call  _printf
```

Where format is "%s". rsi gets set to argv[0].

So, from this, I drew out what (I think) the stack looks like initially:

```
 top of stack
               <- rsp after alignment
return address <- rsp at beginning (aligned rsp + 8)
  [something]  <- rsp + 16
    argc       <- rsp + 24
   argv[0]     <- rsp + 32
   argv[1]     <- rsp + 40
    ...            ...
bottom of stack
```

And so on. Sorry if that's hard to read. I'm wondering what [something] is. After a few tests, I find that it is usually just 0. However, occasionally, it is some (seemingly) random number.

Also, could you tell me if the rest of my stack drawing is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it close.

`argv` is an array *pointer*, not where the array is.  In `C` it is written `char **argv`, so you have to do two levels of dereferencing to get to the strings.

```
 top of stack
               <- rsp after alignment
return address <- rsp at beginning (aligned rsp + 8)
  [something]  <- rsp + 16
    argc       <- rsp + 24
   argv        <- rsp + 32
   envp        <- rsp + 40  (in most Unix-compatible systems, the environment
    ...            ...       string array, char **envp)
bottom of stack
 ...
somewhere else:
   argv[0]     <- argv+0:   address of first parameter (program path or name)
   argv[1]     <- argv+8:   address of second parameter (first command line argument)
   argv[2]     <- argv+16:  address of third parameter (second command line argument)
    ...
   argv[argc]  <-  argv+argc*8:  NULL
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes more sense. But then, why is it that when I do:
"**mov   r10, [rsp + 32]**" and then
"**add   r10, 8**"
and then pass r10 in to printf, I get a segfault? That should be argv[1], right?

Comment: Wait, my **fault**. I think argv is actually "rsp + 40", not 32. Maybe. I'm pretty confused now, but thanks for your help!

Comment: `argc` and `argv` aren't on the stack, x86-64 System V passes the first up-to-6 integer/pointer args in registers.  The OP loading `[rsp+32]` just happened to work if the stuff that called `main` didn't adjust the stack much since process entry (where the `argv[]` array itself is on the stack, so `_start` will do something like `mov edi, [rsp]` (argc) and `lea rsi, [rsp+8]` (argv) to get the args for `main`.  (And another LEA with RDI*8 to get envp).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (3.2.3, Parameter Passing), the parameters for `main(int argc, char **argv)` are passed to (in left-to-right order) `rdi` & `rsi` because they are of INTEGER class. `envp`, if it were used, would be passed into `rdx`, and so forth.
`gcc` places them into the current frame as follows (presumably for convenience? freeing up registers?):

```
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],  edi
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10], rsi
```

When the frame pointer is omitted, the addressing is relative to `rsp`. Normally, `argv` would be one eightbyte below `rbp` (`argc` comes first, although that's not mandated) and therefore:

```
# after prologue
mov    rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10] # or you could grab it from rsi, etc.
add    rax, 0x8
mov    rsi, QWORD PTR [rax]
mov    edi, 0x40064c # format
call   400418 <printf@plt>
```

Comment: *presumably for convenience?* no, because you compiled with optimization disabled, so it spills everything to memory where the debugger can read and write them.  If you compiled with normal optimization, gcc would just use the register values like you would by hand.